# dotnet build/publish library project adds all dependencies

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, github-actions

Within a Visual Studio solution I have several library projects, which generate DLLs.
The DLLs are dynamically loaded from an application, therefor no further dependencies to other libraries (logging, Newtonsoft.Json, application contract DLLs) should be published.

Currently we are using Visual Studio build (msbuild) to copy the DLL to a deploy directory.

We are moving to Github and want to use Github Actions. Which calls the following commands in each project directory:

```
dotnet restore -r win-x64
dotnet build   --runtime win-x64 --self-contained true --configuration Debug --no-restore
dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 --self-contained true --property:PublishDir=deploy --no-restore --no-build
```

However all depended libraries are also copied to the deploy directory.

How can we have more control to have only the DLL be deployed?